# react-hooks-form conflict with reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap, react-hook-form

I'm trying to add `react-hook-form` to my `reactstrap` form and inputs, but looks like it has a conflict between the packages.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import {
    Button,
    Form,
    Label,
    Input
} from 'reactstrap';
import { FormControlLabel, Checkbox, FormGroup } from '@material-ui/core';

...

const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

...

const updDetails = (data) => {
   console.log(data);    
}

return (
   <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(updDetails)}>
      <FormGroup className="mr-10 mb-10">
         <Label for="compName" className="mr-sm-10">Company Name</Label>
         <Input type="text" name="compName" id="compName" placeholder="Company Name"
            ref={register({ required: true })} aria-invalid={errors.name ? "true" : "false"}
            value={compDetails.compName} onChange={(e) => setCompDetails({...compDetails, compName: e.target.value})}
         />
         {errors.name && errors.name.type === "required" && (
            <span role="alert">This is required</span>
         )} 
      </FormGroup>
      <Button type="submit" className="col-sm-3" color="primary">Update Details</Button>
   </Form>
)
...
```

When I load the page, I can see in the browser console warnings for all my inputs: `` Field is missing `name` attribute `` . However, I am adding the name to every input as in the code above. Also, when I click on `Update Details` with an empty value for the `compName` it submits and the data is empty object.
Can't I use `react-hook-form` with `reactstrap`?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if these things are the cause of the problem, but the following things look wrong: You don't need `value` and `onChange` on the `Input`. If you need the value, you can destructure `values` from `useForm`. `errors.name` should really be `errors.compName`. What is also important is, that reactstrap forwards the refs. I am not sure, if it is doing so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have to use `innerRef` instead of `ref` on the `Input` component. i found this in the source [here](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/Input.js#L130).

```
<Input
  type="text"
  name="compName"
  id="compName"
  placeholder="Company Name"
  innerRef={register({ required: true })}
  aria-invalid={errors.compName ? "true" : "false"}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem. How can I set the input border red if there is an error?

Comment: Probably use the invalid property similarly to the `aria-invalid` (set to true if `errors.compName` is not null/undefined). The docs might be helpful as well as the source code.

Comment: Typescript won't allow using `innerRef` this way, complaining `Type 'UseFormRegisterReturn<"argName">' is not assignable to type 'Ref<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement> | undefined'`

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the `reactstrap` code, but a thing you could do is pass the name to the register function, use it this way:

```
ref={register({name: 'input-name', /* rest of options*/})}
```

Hope I could help :D

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do this in 2023 and with Typescript, then you'll get a TS error when trying to assign a bunch of properties output by `register(...)` to `innerRef` that only expects one element of one of the 3 types, so you'll see something like this:  `Type 'UseFormRegisterReturn<"compName">' is not assignable to type 'Ref<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement> | undefined'`

Replacing the `ref` part of the `register(...)` output with `innerRef` solved it for me:

```js
const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors }
    } = useForm();

const registerRs = (fieldName: string, options = {}) => {
        const registeredField: Partial<UseFormRegisterReturn> = register(fieldName, options);
        const ref = registeredField.ref;
        delete registeredField.ref;
        return {...registeredField, innerRef: ref};
    }

...

<Input
  type="text"
  id="compName"
  placeholder="Company Name"
  {...registerRs("compName", { required: true })}
  aria-invalid={errors.compName ? "true" : "false"}
/>
```